# How do I access an array inside an object?

Tags: php, arrays, object, joomla

I am trying to retrieve the information inside the "source" but I cant seem to find the correct way to do it.

```
object(JInstaller)#163 (16) {
["_paths":protected]=>
array(5) {
  ["source"]=>
  string(95) "/var/zpanel/hostdata/desarrollo/public_html/complusoft_net/demo-j2517/tmp/install_53679ce0c6870"
```

**Please note that the path property is protected**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, I hope this helps other people:

```
JInstaller::getInstance()->getPath('source');
```

Answer (score 2):

Straightforward

```
$obj->_paths["source"]
```

Of course this only works when `_paths` is public - for a protected attribute you need a helper method.

```
public function getPath() {
    return $this->_paths;
}
```

and can then use something like

```
$obj->getPath()["source"]
```

or

```
$path = $obj->getPath();
$path["source"]
```

Comment: The `_path` property is protected, so that is not going to work.

Comment: That is what I thought too but wasnt sure

Comment: @kingkero Its not returning anything :(

Comment: @MONZTAAA As I said you need a helper method. Can you implement one/does one already exist?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Joomla, you would need:

```
$your_object->getPath('source');
```